# Set all datetime properties in object and subobjects to local time

Tags: c#

I'm working on a method that will handle any object, and update all of the object's properties and subobjects' properties that are datetimes to local time for said user.

Below is the working method to update to local time.

```
    public static DateTime ToTimeZoneTime(DateTime time, string timeZoneId = "Pacific Standard Time")
    {
        TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
        return ToTimeZoneTime(time, tzi);
    }

    public static DateTime ToTimeZoneTime(DateTime time, TimeZoneInfo tzi)
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(time, tzi);
    }
```

And here is the method I'm working on currently to get local time for any object.  I'm getting a overflow error when trying to update sub ojects. Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

```
public static void ToLocalTime<T>(T obj, string timeZoneId)
{
        Type t = obj.GetType();

        // Loop through the properties.
        PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            PropertyInfo p = props[i];
            // If a property is DateTime or DateTime?, set DateTimeKind to DateTimeKind.Utc.
            if (p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                DateTime date = (DateTime)p.GetValue(obj, null);
                date = ToTimeZoneTime(date, timeZoneId);
                p.SetValue(obj, date, null);
            }
            // Same check for nullable DateTime.
            else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>))
            {
                DateTime? date = (DateTime?)p.GetValue(obj, null);
                if (date.HasValue)
                {
                    DateTime? newDate = ToTimeZoneTime(date.Value, timeZoneId);
                    p.SetValue(obj, newDate, null);
                }
            }

            if (p.PropertyType.IsClass && p.PropertyType != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
            {
                ToLocalTime(p, timeZoneId);
            }
        }
```

Comment: exactly what error where?

Comment: The error happens in recursion so after if (p.PropertyType.IsClass && p.PropertyType != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))

Comment: You're passing the property info object to your recursion and not the object/value represented by that property. You'd have to GetValue and pass that, but since it'd be type object you'd have to construct a generic method call with reflection to call the right version of it. At which point it gets messy especially if you aren't Caching a delegate of some sort for each Type to do all the work (reflection is expensive). Also You're only calling the recursion for Classes that are enumerable which seems maybe(?) wrong. Also value types can have datetime properties as well

Comment: Though generics may be somewhat moot since you're calling `GetType` manually instead of `typeof(T)`. You can ditch the generics and change the parameter type to `object` then at least you wouldn't have to construct the generic method call. But if you do that you then lose (or rather make more difficult) the ability to cache the necessary reflection. Btw if you're last `if` is to prevent processing of primitives (like `int` or `float` and the enumerable bit is supposed to be `!=`) you can still handle value types by checking for `TypeCode.Object`, though you'd probably wanna skip `Nullable<>`